# Switch from UIViewController to SKSCene doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've started to create a battle game with Spritekit.

I have a splash screen and main menu.
I used UIViewController to create these two pages and SKScene to create a game scene.
Now in MainMenu I want to switch to GameScene in Play button action
but the GameScene doesn't show anything.
I have break points in GameScene, and surprisingly all the codes in didMoveToView is running but my page dent switch to GameScene
and I am still in MainMenu.

I used the following code to switch from uiviewcontroller to game scene:

```
@IBAction func playButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let scene = GameScene(size:view.bounds.size)//(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)


}
```

the

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(myLabel)
}
```

is running and I can navigate to it by break points.

Comment: Did you try to view the UI Hierarchy when debugging?

Comment: Yes, but do you mean anything special in it?

Comment: Is the sk view visible? Try to set the labels size or the background color of the scene, maybe the scene is shown but empty.

Comment: i can see the sk view in UI Hierarchy and the hidden property of it is unchecked.

Comment: what do you mean 2 pages?  how are you swapping from page 1 to page 2,  it seems to me the game scene is active, but you never present the view.  BTW, I recommend not using GameScene(size:view.bounds.size) in conjunction with aspect fill,  you will only confuse yourself later.  Either pick a static size that allows scaling, or use the resizeFill scalemode

Comment: the two pages are splash screen and main menu.
they are both uiviewcontroller, so i can easily switch between them, but now i want to swap from main menu to game scene which is skview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the problem.
I had to remove all the objects like UIImages, Buttons, Labels,... from superview. 
like this :

```
       for view in self.view.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
       }
```

They didn't let the GameScene Nodes to be presented.